# Show that $\vdash \Gamma \cup \{\psi\}$ implies $\vdash \Gamma \cup \{\psi'\}$ where $\psi'$ is $\psi$ with one of its bound variables renamed.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

My textbook says that it is clear that:

$\vdash \Gamma \cup \{\psi\}$ implies $\vdash \Gamma \cup \psi'$, where $\psi'$ is just $\psi$ with one of its bound variables renamed.

I am trying to show this for myself, but I find substitution/renaming/replacing more of a semantic idea than a syntactic one, can you show this formally?

---

For a semantic approach, by soundness, $\vdash \Gamma \cup \psi$ implies $\models \lor (\Gamma \cup \psi)$. So there is a model $M$ and an assignment $a$ so that $M\models (\lor (\Gamma \cup \psi))[a]$. So that $M \models \psi[a]$ or $M \models \sim \psi [a]$. From here, can I simply pass to another assignment $b$, where $b$ is the same as $a$ only different on the specific variable where $\psi$ and $\psi'$ differ, and climb back up with $M \models \psi'[b]$ or $M\models \sim \psi'[b]$ therefore $M \models \Gamma \cup \psi'$ and by completeness $\vdash \Gamma \cup \psi?$

---

Two issues I see with my proof:

1) The last step is not really completentess, copmleteness says $\Sigma \models \phi \rightarrow \Sigma \vdash \phi$, which is the converse of correctness, but here I'm using it as more of a converse to 'soundness'.

2) Passing to the assignment $b$ is unjustified, even though for some reason it doesn't feel wrong.

Comment: Which is your textbook? What do you mean by $\vdash \Gamma \cup \psi$? Which derivation rules are you allowed to use? In general, formulas are usually defined modulo renaming of bound variables, so $\psi'= \psi$ and hence your question usually does not make sense (since the answer is trivial).

Comment: Why do you find substitution or renaming a semantic idea at all? What is your definition of substitution and renaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

*Note* : I'll move $\Gamma$ to the left of $\vdash$ because the usual *derivation* relation holds between a set $\Gamma$ of formulas and a *single* formula $\psi$ (a derivation has zero or more premises and a *single* conclusion).

IMO; a complete proof must be on induction on the complexity of $\psi$, but the key-point is the base case that we can assume as : $\psi := \forall x \phi$.

I'll assume for simplicity that $\Gamma$ and $\psi$ are *sentences*.

From the derivation $\Gamma \vdash \psi$ we can easily manufacture the derivation $\Gamma \vdash \psi'$, where $\psi' := \forall z \phi(x/z)$, with $z$ new.

The details depend on the proof system: with [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7) we have to use $(\forall \text E)$ and $(\forall \text I)$ rules, while with an Hilbert system we have to use the "typical" quantifier axiom : $\forall x \phi \to \phi(x/t)$ and the meta-theorem : $\Sigma \vdash \phi \text { iff } \Sigma \vdash \forall x \phi$.

For the Hilbert case, starting from : $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$, we have to use the following instance of the quantifier axiom : $\vdash \forall x \phi \to \phi(x/z)$ with *Modus Ponens* to get : $\Gamma \vdash \phi(x/z)$.

Then use the instance of the meta-theorem : if $\Gamma \vdash \phi(x/z)$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall z \phi(x/z)$ to get :

> $\Gamma \vdash \forall z \phi(x/z)$.

---

The symbol $\vdash \Gamma \cup \{ \psi \}$ probably means that you are working with a "Gentzen-style" proof system.

See e.g. Mordechai Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic for Computer Science (Springer, 3rd ed. 2012)](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA51), page 51-on, where we say that we can prove a *set* $U$ of formulas : $\vdash U$.

The proof is the same; if we have a proof-tree for $\vdash \Gamma \cup \{ \psi \}$ we can re-use the same proof-tree for $\vdash \Gamma \cup \{ \psi' \}$, where $\psi' := \forall z \phi(x/z)$.

When we have to "manage" the $\psi'$ formula, the [rules for $\gamma$- and $\delta$- quantified formulas](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA155) works "uniformly".

The result of deriving $\phi(z/a)$ from $\forall z \phi(x/z)$ is the same as that of deriving $\phi(x/a)$ from $\forall x \phi$.